# Using Hadamard Form of a Matrix in the Block Cipher

Tags: block-cipher, finite-field, xor, mds

**Definition:** A matrix **A** of size $2^n$ is a  *Hadamard* matrix, if has the following form 
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
U & V \\
V & U
\end{array}
\right)_{2^n\times 2^n}\, ,
$$
where $U$ and $V$ are also Hadamard matrices.

*Example:*  A Hadamard matrix **A** of size $2^2$ is as follows 
$$
A= \left( \begin {array}{cccc} a_{{0}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}
\\ a_{{1}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{2}}
\\ a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{1}}
\\ a_{{3}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{0}}\end {array}
 \right)\, ,
$$
Where $a_i$, $0\leq i \leq 3$ are from any arbitrary field.

Consider **B** is a $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix such that the $(i,j)$the entry of **B**, denoted **B**$[i,j]$, is defined by **B**$[i,j]=a_{i \oplus j}$ where $i,j \in \{0,1,\cdots , 2^{n}-1\}$ and $i \oplus j$ means Xor between two numbers $i$ and $j$(for example $2 \oplus 3=1$ since $10 \oplus 11=01$).

*Example:* A matrix **B** of size $2^3$ is 
$$
B=
 \left( \begin {array}{cccccccc} a_{{0}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{4
}}&a_{{5}}&a_{{6}}&a_{{7}}\\ a_{{1}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{3}}
&a_{{2}}&a_{{5}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{7}}&a_{{6}}\\ a_{{2}}&a
_{{3}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{6}}&a_{{7}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{5}}
\\ a_{{3}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{7}}&a_{{6}}&a
_{{5}}&a_{{4}}\\ a_{{4}}&a_{{5}}&a_{{6}}&a_{{7}}&a_{
{0}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}\\ a_{{5}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{7
}}&a_{{6}}&a_{{1}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{2}}\\a_{{6}}
&a_{{7}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{5}}&a_{{2}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{0}}&a_{{1}}
\\ a_{{7}}&a_{{6}}&a_{{5}}&a_{{4}}&a_{{3}}&a_{{2}}&a
_{{1}}&a_{{0}}\end {array} \right)=a_{i \oplus j}\qquad 
0\leq i,j \leq 7 \, .
$$

**My question:** Why the matrix **B**=$(a_{i \oplus j})$, $0\leq i,j \leq 2^{n}-1$, is an $2^n\times 2^n$ Hadamard matrix?

*My Try:* I can proof it by induction on $n$, but I would like to see its proof with other method.

*Background:* When entries of a Hadamard matrix come from the finite field $GF(2^q)$ and be an [**MDS** matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix), then the Hadamard matrix can be used in the diffusion layer of block cipher such as [Khazad block cipher](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228924670_The_Khazad_legacy-level_block_cipher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is evident. Let $B$ be a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix. We have:

> $$a_{i\oplus (j+2^{n-1})}=a_{(2^{n-1}+i)\oplus j},a_{i\oplus j}=a_{(2^{n-1}+i)\oplus (2^{n-1}+j)}.$$

So, $B$ has the following form and therefore is a Hadamard matrix as follows
$$B=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
U & V \\
V & U
\end{array}
\right)_{2^n\times 2^n}\, $$

Comment: Meysam, I suggest to add the condition $i,j \in \{0,1,\cdots, 2^{n-1}-1\}$ in your answer, since in the posted question it is assumed that $i,j \in \{0,1,\cdots, 2^{n}-1\}$. In fact, I wrote the values of $i$ and $j$ incorrectly and after that I edited the question and I modified it. Thanks

Comment: @kodlu can I ask a math writing question. What is difference of *be* and *is* in math writing. I mean, in which situation it's better to use *be* instead of *is*. Thanks

Comment: this is an English question.  In modern English we say " let X be Y" or  "assume X is Y",  both are essentially the same.

Comment: This answer made me think whether the following cayley table has a Hadamard structure, as seen in this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71288/whats-the-number-of-unique-possible-cayley-tables-in-a-1616-grid-for-xoring-s